# Handling jQuery.noConflict

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have inherited scripts that begin like this:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

But I have no idea why this is done. I understand that we're trying to resolve conflicts but how can I find which conflict it is trying to resolve?

If we can't find the actual conflict, we're planning to revert to **`$`** instead of **`$j`** and look if any conflict appears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main reason we use `Jquery.noConflict` is when there are other javascript libraries that uses "`$`" for selector/function/variable .
If you need to find where exactly the conflict happens, just run code without assinging Jquery.noConflict and check if the excepted result are coming as well the console window of developer tab.

As always documentation is the key - https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Thanks for a good answer. I accept this one because you actually say how to find where the conflict is.

Comment: Thanks @DacSaunders happy that helped.

Answer (score 2):

According to jQuery docs

> Many JavaScript libraries use $ as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, $ is just an alias for jQuery, so all functionality is available without using $. If you need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, return control of $ back to the other library with a call to $.noConflict(). Old references of $ are saved during jQuery initialization; noConflict() simply restores them.
>
> If for some reason two versions of jQuery are loaded (which is not
> recommended), calling $.noConflict( true ) from the second version
> will return the globally scoped jQuery variables to those of the first
> version.
>
> Here is another [link](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/) of docs that can explain very well

In simple words

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

after this we enter in no conflict mode so we can now use $j instead of $ or jQuery and that code will not Conflict with previous versions of Jquery or libraries using $ or jQuery

Answer (score 1):

`$` is an alias used for `jQuery`. If in your application there comes an case when you are using `$` for some other purpose, then you need to use some other non-conflicting variable to prevent conflicts.

Also, there could be another case, when there is more than one version of `jQuery` being used in your application or modules within your application which will then result in conflicts. So you need to avoid conflicts by using `jQuery.noConflict();`.

You can read more about it on [jQuery.noConflict](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)